# Delete an entire collection through Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

### Delete collection through a function created in Cloud Functions

I need to delete an entire collection with multiple documents when a user is deleted, so I decided to create a function so that it fires whenever a user is deleted.

Below is the code.

[Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) (**index.js**):

```
  exports.onUserDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
    deleteCollection(admin.firestore(), user.uid, 15);
  });

  function deleteCollection(db, collectionPath, batchSize) {
    var collectionRef = db.collection(collectionPath);
    var query = collectionRef.orderBy('__name__').limit(batchSize);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
    });
  }

  function deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject) {
    query.get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          // When there are no documents left, we are done
          if (snapshot.size === 0) {
            return 0;
          }

          // Delete documents in a batch
          var batch = db.batch();
          snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            batch.delete(doc.ref);
          });

          return batch.commit().then(() => {
            return snapshot.size;
          });
        }).then((numDeleted) => {
          if (numDeleted === 0) {
            resolve();
            return;
          }

          // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
          // exploding the stack.
          process.nextTick(() => {
            deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
          });
        })
        .catch(reject);
  }
```

**When attempting to perform the firebase deploy command --only functions the following error occurs:**

65:11  warning  Arrow function expected no return value     consistent-return

65:18  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting

69:11  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

✖ 3 problems (1 error, 2 warnings)

**What am I doing wrong?**

**How can I delete the entire collection when the user is deleted?**

If you can post the above code with the logic that I should apply, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do as follows:

```
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.onUserDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {

    const collectionRef = db.collection(user.uid);

    var promises = [];

    return collectionRef.get()
    .then(qs => {
       qs.forEach(docSnapshot => {
         promises.push(docSnapshot.ref.delete());
       });
       return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return false; 
    });
});
```

As reflected by your code and as advised in the documentation (see excerpt below) you may delete the docs by batch if the collection is very large. I let you adapt the above code for this, if you consider it is necessary.

> If you have larger collections, you may want to delete the documents in smaller batches to avoid out-of-memory errors. Repeat the
>   process until you've deleted the entire collection or subcollection.
>   *Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections*